# How yield return is interpreted by foreach loop ?

Tags: c#

How `yield return` is interpreted by `foreach` loop ?

`foreach` loop looks something like this:

```
var tmp = obj.GetEnumerator();
int i; // up to C# 4.0
while(tmp.MoveNext()) {
    int i; // C# 5.0
    i = tmp.Current;
    {...} // your code
}
```

As far as I understood, compiler must somehow substitute `yield return` with `MoveNext()` & `Current`(property) from IEnumerable/IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler creates a state machine which moves to next state every time you call `MoveNext()` and return proper value for current state by `Current` property.

This state machine may be infinite (e.g. when you place `yield return` inside infinite loop) or [finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). When it's finite as the last state `MoveNext()` returns `false` to let caller know that there are no more results.

There is pretty nice article about that by Jon Skeet: [Iterator block implementation details: auto-generated state machines](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx).